# How to get caller id variable?

Tags: asterisk

I am receiving call in one trunk and forwarding that call by second trunk with following

```
[from-trunk1]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/trunk2/12345678)
```

Now I'd like to add IF condition. If callerid of a user calling to trunk1 is 112233, then I'd like to forward it to 445566 from trunk2.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the caller ID [as part of the extension pattern](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching#PatternMatching-MatchingonCallerID).

```
exten => _X./112233,1,Dial(SIP/trunk2/445566)
```

The CID pattern can accept all the same special characters as the destination pattern if you prefix it with `_`.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone interested

```
[from-trunk1]
; if caller is 112233 go 50
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(num)}" = "112233"]?50)

; if not code below
exten => _X.,n,Playback(tt-monkeys)

; if condition where true, start from 50
exten => _X.,50,Dial(SIP/trunk2/445566)
```

Please suggest, if you have better code.

Comment: This code is much worse then miken32 suggested. It will be executed for ANY incoming calls. Use patern matching, asterisk designed that way.